# Константные выражения

Tags: delphi, pascal

Допустим я объявляю

```pascal
var
  a, b: Integer;
const
  c = a + b;
```

Оно не скомпилируется потому что константы должны быть константными.
Это я понимаю, но например в плюсах это можно сделать препроцессорной директивой.

```cpp
  Int a, b;
  #define c (a + b)
```

А как это сделать в pascal(/delphi)?

---

Самое подходящее что мне приходит в голову это инлайн функция без параметров.
Её как-раз можно вызывать без скобочек.
Но может есть что-то лучше?

Аля

```py
function c():Integer; inline;
begin
  Result := a + b;
end;
```

Но возникает проблема что если я хочу использовать это для сокращения оригинальных имен, то ввод придется менять.

Можно еще загнать всё в класс а-ля:

```pascal
type
  cl = class
  public
    a, b: Integer;
    property c read a + b write @@@;
end;
```

Comment: никак, в делфи (до xe8, дальше я не в курсе) - нету ничего похожего.

Comment: и хорошо, что нету

Comment: А чего хочется в результате добиться?

Comment: `property c read a + b` так делать нельзя(было?)

Comment: лучше приведите пример конкретной проблемы, которую хотите этим решить. а то пока что не понятно с какой стороны и к чему это прикладывать надо.

Comment: `function c():Integer; inline;` - это, насколько я понимаю, и есть наиболее близкий по смыслу вариант к `#define c (a + b);`.